# Best practice for reusing controller functions

Tags: laravel

I have the following function in one of my controllers. The project has grown quite big and I now need to use this same function across a couple of my controllers. What would be the best practice to do this?

I've looked into service providers but something about it looks quite overkill to me or is this the best way to do it.

Are service providers best suited for complex functions as opposed to simple ones?

In the past I've just created simple PHP helper files and then imported them into controllers via "use".

```
public function createPayByLink(Request $request) {

    $token = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $token = bin2hex($token);

    $pbl = new PayByLink();
    $pbl->email = $request->email;
    $pbl->amount = $request->amount;
    $pbl->currency = $request->currency;
    $pbl->merchantTransactionId = $request->merchantTransactionId;
    $pbl->hash = $token;
    $pbl->merchantName = $request->channel['merchantName'];
    $pbl->channelUuid = $request->channel['channelUuid'];
    $pbl->channelLogin = $request->channel['userId'];
    $pbl->channelPwd = $request->channel['password'];
    $pbl->save();

    if($request->emailSwitch) {
        Mail::to($request->email)->send(new PayByLinkEmail($request, $token));
    }
    return $pbl;
}
```

Comment: Is it just the creating of the `PayByLink` or are you wanting to include the `Mail` send as well?

Comment: @Rwd The Mail send too mate.

Comment: The simplest way would probably be to just create a trait with that method in it.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to extract duplicated code to a separate service. Those services can than be injected into every controller which needs to do the same thing. Keep in mind that it's better to split certain pieces of code by what they do, rather than what other code they are surrounded with. Doing so I came up with something like this:

### app/Http/Controllers/PayController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repository\PayRepository;
use App\Service\PayMailer;
use App\Service\TokenGenerator;

class PayController
{
    /** @var PayRepository */
    private $repository;

    /** @var PayMailer */
    private $mailer;

    /** @var TokenGenerator */
    private $tokenGenerator;

    public function __construct(
        PayRepository $repository,
        PayMailer $mailer,
        TokenGenerator $tokenGenerator
    ) {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->tokenGenerator = $tokenGenerator;
    }

    public function createPayByLink(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $this->tokenGenerator->createToken();

        $pbl = $this->repository->save(
            $token,
            $request->email,
            $request->amount,
            $request->currency,
            $request->merchantTransactionId,
            $request->channel['merchantName'],
            $request->channel['channelUuid'],
            $request->channel['userId'],
            $request->channel['password']
        );

        if ($request->emailSwitch) {
            $this->mailer->send($request->email, $token, $request);
        }

        return $pbl;
    }
}
```

### app/Repository/PayRepository.php

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Service\TokenGenerator;

class PayRepository
{
    public function save(
        $token,
        $email,
        $amount,
        $currency,
        $merchantTransactionId,
        $merchantName,
        $channelUuid,
        $channelLogin,
        $channelPwd
    ): PayByLink {
        $pbl = new PayByLink();
        $pbl->email = $email;
        $pbl->amount = $amount;
        $pbl->currency = $currency;
        $pbl->merchantTransactionId = $merchantTransactionId;
        $pbl->hash = $token;
        $pbl->merchantName = $merchantName;
        $pbl->channelUuid = $channelUuid;
        $pbl->channelLogin = $channelLogin;
        $pbl->channelPwd = $channelPwd;
        $pbl->save();

        return $pbl;
    }
}
```

### app/Service/PayMailer.php

```
namespace App\Service;

class PayMailer
{
    public function send($email, $token, $request): void
    {
        Mail::to($request->email)->send(new PayByLinkEmail($request, $token));
    }
}
```

### app/Service/TokenGenrator.php

```
namespace App\Service;

class TokenGenerator
{
    public function createToken(): string
    {
        $token = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

        return bin2hex($token);
    }
}
```